# Sitemap Generator detect Only Home Page and also screaming frog detects only homepage

Tags: wordpress, seo, xml-sitemap

I am trying to generate sitemap for my website but its detecting only homepage. The following generator I used https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/

Even Yoast SEO plugin sitemap is not accepted in google webmaster tool where it says "
Your Sitemap appears to be an HTML page. Please use a supported sitemap format instead."

Anyone please help me to find the solution for this problem.

Thanks
Manoj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep using Yoast SEO plugin, it also generates XML sitemaps, just enable the option then upload them to google webmaster tool.

Here is how this can be done:
https://kb.yoast.com/kb/enable-xml-sitemaps-in-the-wordpress-seo-plugin/

You might also want to make sure that only things that you want to be indexed in Google index are existing in the sitemaps, because Yoast SEO generates XML maps for all posts types, testimonies, bookings, etc... (This can be also customized)

Comment: Thanks, I am using Yoast SEO plugin but still the sitemap is not accepted in google webmaster tool. Even it doesn't work after I disable and enable the sitemap in plugin.

Comment: You are saying that you are trying to upload HTML sitemaps, you should enable yoast SEO XML sitemaps then upload XML sitemaps